# ActionController::ParameterMissing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have made an application that has a `personsController` class, with an action show and new. I also created the `Person` model this way:

```
rails generate model Person name:string surname:string partner:references
```

The `partner` field should reference another person. In the new action I created a form to insert a new person into the database:

```
<%= form_for :person , url: persons_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :surname %>
        <%= f.text_field :surname %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :partner %>
        <%= f.number_field :partner , value: 0 %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This is the `personsController` method create:

```
def create
    @person= Person.new(post_params)
    @Person.save
    redirect_to @person

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:partner,:name,:surname);
    end
```

The problem is that I get an error when I submit the form:

[image]

**Update**

I changed the instruction to:

```
params.require(:person).permit(:partner,:name,:surname);
```

But I still get an error:

> NameError in PersonsController#create
>   uninitialized constant Person::Partner

Person model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem here:

From your model `post` is not a defined attribute

so changed this:

```
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:partner,:name,:surname);
    end
```

to

```
    def post_params
        params.require(:person).permit(:partner_id,:name,:surname)  
    end
```

### EDIT

use partner_id instead of partner for your foreign key

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :partner %>
    <%= f.number_field :partner_id, value: 0 %>
</p>
```

Comment: I still get an error: "NameError in PersonsController#create,
uninitialized constant Person::Partner".

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri please post your person model too

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I just edited my answer, you should use partner_id instead of partner for your foreign key in the view

Comment: If I do that Person.new returns nil (undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass).

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri in your controller change partner to partner_id too, as the latest edit depicts

Comment: \@Person.save should be \@person.save

Comment: look at the case small letter p and not capital letter

Answer (score 2):

Require `person`:

```
params.require(:person).permit(:partner, :name, :surname)
```

Comment: I still get an error: "NameError in PersonsController#create,
uninitialized constant Person::Partner".