# Rails Application Controller missing param that is not missing

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simlar problem like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733697/actioncontrollerparametermissing)

My Controller has this function:

```
    def user_params
       params.require(:login)
       params.require(:password).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :login, :password,:position)
    end
```

And I get the error

```
 `param not found: login`
```

This is the post request.

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"H+Z0dGaheQPjl3T+0zcGHw3NFYkQ1HLccG1ETcQFbsk=",
 "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Max",
 "last_name"=>"Werner",
 "position"=>"Business Dev Analyst",
 "login"=>"login",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

The issue is that I do have a column in my table called login. I checked via mysql in the command line. I created an entry by hand and the index function the login without a problem... same hash   :login

Why does it throw an error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requiring the param of `login` to be at the "top level" of the parameters hash.  In your post request, the `login` and `password` params are nested within the `user` param.

I'd suggest doing something like:

`params.require(:user).permit(:login, :password)`

If you absolutely want to check to make sure `login` and `password` are included, you could do:

```
def user_params
  required_params = params.require(:user)

  required_params.require(:login)
  required_params.require(:password)

  required_params.permit(<permitted_params>)
end
```

You *can* chain method calls together, but remember that `require` returns the parameter at the given key:

```
1.9.3p484 :001 > params = { :name => { :first => "Chris" } }
 => {:name=>{:first=>"Chris"}} 

1.9.3p484 :002 > ActionController::Parameters.new(params).require(:name).require(:first)
 => "Chris"
```

So, if you want to use chaining, your method would look something like this:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user)

  params.require(:user).require(:login)
  params.require(:user).require(:password)

  params.require(:user).permit(<permitted_params>)
end
```

My *opinion* is that the former is cleaner, but either way will get you the results you want.

[The documentation on parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) is actually really good and gives a lot of examples.  I'd highly recommend checking it out.

Comment: Thanks, it works as long as I have separate lines for each required and then one line for required_params.permit(:.... :.... :....). I though you could daisy chain things in rails. why do I need to have them separate here?

Comment: You *could* do that, with respect to the `require` statements...  I'll update my answer and explain.